# Eclipse: quick run/preview vs. run main

Tags: java, eclipse-luna

I am wondering why they 'quick run/preview' displays object different that when you select 'main run' in Eclipse. I personally find that objects look better/neater/more elegant in quick run/preview mode than when I when I run and compile the application via the 'main run' option.

Can anyone tell me there is such a big difference, and what I need to do to actually make my application and its objects look like in 'quick run/preview' mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick run/preview in Eclipse is used to compile the code and run it more efficiently than normal run. I'm assuming you are referring to this when you are building GUI's?

Anyhow, quick run/preview is just to quickly preview your application regardless of the looks.

I'm assuming you want your GUI to have the Look and Feel of a Windows application rather than the "metal" Java GUI look.

This is done relatively easy as you can both make the "Look and Feel" of your application be based on whatever OS you are running or which one you prefer.

Refer to this simple article [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).

Comment: Thank you. That provided an answer to my question.